# Create an array of JavaScript objects from an existing array of objects

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

my first time posting a question here, so please let me know if I'm missing any information that is needed. Updated to include desired output.

I'm working on a google app script (basically javascript) and am trying to pull objects from an array of objects and create a new array of objects. I'm using the google base functions for getRowData (these can be found at : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets) to create my initial array of objects. This gives me a row of data similar (A JIRA export if anyone is wondering, with information cut):

```
{summary=Internal - Fix PuppetFile Jenkins Jobs, progress=1.0, issueType=Story, resolution=Done, timeSpent=3600.0, key=XXXXX-646, watchers=0.0, remainingEstimate=0.0, numberOfComments=1.0, status=Resolved, assignee=XXXXXXXX}
```

When I run my function:

```
for (var i = 0; i < issueList.length; i++){

rankList[i] = [issueList[i].summary,issueList[i].storyPoints,issueList[i].epicLink,issueList[i].fixVersions];
}
```

I get:

```
[Internal - Fix PuppetFile Jenkins Jobs, 3.0, null, null]
```

But what I want is:

```
{summary=Internal - Fix PuppetFile Jenkins Jobs, storyPoints=1.0, epicLink=StoryName, fixVersions=Done}
```

I'm not getting the key for the value, and I don't understand how the objects are constructed quite well enough to get it to transfer over. I looked at some examples of manipulating the key/value pairs but when I tried it on my own I just got a bunch of undefined. Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: That's not a valid object, objects are `key:val` not `key=val`

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. The title says "create an array of Javascript objects", but you're creating an array of arrays, not an array of objects.

Comment: We could help you better if you showed what you're hoping to get.

Comment: Updated with "what I want"

Comment: What you want isn't a valid JS object, did you see tymeJV's comment?

Comment: I don't see where `StoryName`appears in the input. Where is that value supposed to come from?

Comment: I guess I should paste the code that I'm using from google to generate the initial array of objects. There is a huge list of data and I just truncated it to paste it, but I can do the full dump if people need it. I am positive the data is in the giant list. On reflection, I pasted a link to the google code example I am using as there is a lot of code there. If you think I should repaste here I can do it, just don't know what would be easier.

Comment: We don't need the full list, just be consistent between your input and output, so we I can see the correspondence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is probably something like this:

```
rankList = [];
for (var i = 0; i < issueList.length; i++) {
    issue = issueList[i];
    rankList.push({
        summary: issue.summary,
        storyPoints: issue.progress,
        epicLink: issue.IDONTKNOW,
        fixVersions: issue.resolution
    });
}
```

I don't know what field goes in `epicLink`, since it wasn't obvious from your example. And I was just guessing about the other fields. But this is the general structure, you just need to make all the correct correspondences.

Comment: That does what I'm looking for, now I just have to get it to write out properly but I think I can take it from here. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score -1):

Use jquery each instead it's much easier to get the keys and value at the same time:

```
var myarray = [];

$.each(issueList,function(key,value){
  console.log(key);
  console.log(value);

  value.key = key;

  myarray.push(value);
});

console.log(myarray);
```

Comment: If I can use jQuery inside google apps that would be neat, and if you have a library I can add to do so please let me know how I would do that.