# Google Sheet to Firestore multiple documents

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to write data to Firestore from Google Sheet. At the moment I am testing this code and it is working fine, but it only creates a document for me.

My question is: how can I create multiple documents in a single execution of the `sendFirestore()` function?

```
function sendFirestore() {
  const email = "...";
  const key = "...";
  const projectId = "...";

  var firestore = FirestoreApp.getFirestore (email, key, projectId); 

  const data = [
    {
      "id": "proveedor1",
      "name": "direccion1"
    },
    {
      "id": "proveedor2",
      "name": "direccion2"
    },
    {
      "id": "proveedor3",
      "name": "direccion3"
    },

  ];

  firestore.createDocument("proveedores", data);
}
```

Comment: It looks like calling `firestore.createDocument(...)` multiple times should create multiple documents. Did you try that?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have not tried, could you guide me or give me an example please?

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a site where we write your code for you. I recommend giving it a try for yourself, and then posting back if you can't get it to work.

Comment: @PacoZevallos I know nothing about Firebase, but since the code is being written as a script, I would expect that you would be able to create a loop in which 1) `data` and other relevant info, such as the name of the document, is created from data in the spreadsheet, and then 2) `firestore.createDocument(xxx);` creates the document. There are plenty of precedents for this process. The starting point would be for you to create (and share) a Google spreadsheet containing the data/testdata that you wish to use. Then we can look at a specific coding "problem".

Comment: @Tedinoz Thanks for the contribution I will try to find information on how a loop is made, if you have any reference I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You want to know "how can I create multiple documents in a single execution of the sendFirestore() function?"

There are several ways that this might be done.
For instance, you might create several unique instances of `data`, and execute `firestore.createDocument();` after each one.
This is not particularly efficient or convenient, but it is possible.

`var data01 = ...;`
`firestore.createDocument("document1",data01);`
`var data02 = ...;`
`firestore.createDocument("document2",data02);`
`var data03 = ...;`
`firestore.createDocument("document3",data03);`

Rather than edit the script, it would be more efficient and convenient to enter the data into the Google spreadsheet and then retrieve it. The key to this approach is to create a loop in which i) the data is retrieved and ii) `createdocument` is executed. This would enable you to create as many documents as you wish.

In the following example, there are a couple of things to note:

- there is a `for` statement to enable looping through the rows
- the format for `data` is somewhat unusual - an array of objects; I applied a variation on the methods suggested in [Create an array of JavaScript objects from an existing array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19339055/1330560) and [Turn object into array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42767355/1330560)
- I have assumed (for the sake of convenience) that there are only 3 fields and these are added long-hand; of course this is most unlikely in real-life. A more elegant solution would be to create a nested loop which would loop through the columns on each row in order to build the `data`. Such an approach would also cater for different numbers of data elements on each row (that is, for each document).
- the code is untested in so far as firebase is concerned.

---

The spreadsheet might look like this:

Example spreadsheet
[image: Spreadsheet screenshot]

---

The code outputs the three `data` values like this:
 - `[{name=abc1_1, id=xyz1_1}, {name=abc1_2, id=xyz1_2}, {name=abc1_3, id=xyz1_3}]`
 - `[{name=abc2_1, id=xyz2_1}, {name=abc2_2, id=xyz2_2}, {name=abc2_3, id=xyz2_3}]`
 - `[{name=abc3_1, id=xyz3_1}, {name=abc3_2, id=xyz3_2}, {name=abc3_3, id=xyz3_3}]`

---

```
function so5745433303() {

  // Firestore setup
  const email = "...";
  const key = "...";
  const projectId = "...";
  var firestore = FirestoreApp.getFirestore (email, key, projectId); 

  // get document data from ther spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetname = "firebase_data3";
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname); 
  // get the last row and column in order to define range
  var sheetLR = sheet.getLastRow(); // get the last row
  var sheetLC = sheet.getLastColumn(); // get the last column
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: Last row = "+sheetLR+", and Last Column = "+sheetLC);  
  var dataSR = 3; // the first row of data
  // define the data range
  var sourceRange = sheet.getRange(3,1,sheetLR-dataSR+1,sheetLC);
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the source range is "+sourceRange.getA1Notation());
  // get the data
  var sourceData = sourceRange.getValues();
  // get the number of length of the object in order to establish a loop value
  var sourceLen = sourceData.length;
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the source data length = "+sourceLen);

  // Loop through the rows
  for (var i=0;i<sourceLen;i++){
    var data = [];
    var title = sourceData[i][0];
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: the document title is "+title);

    // #1 ID and Name
    data.push({
      "id": sourceData[i][1],
      "name": sourceData[i][2]
    });
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: id#1 is "+sourceData[i][1]+", and name#1 = "+sourceData[i][2]); 

    // #2 ID and Name
    data.push({
      "id": sourceData[i][3],
      "name": sourceData[i][4]
    });  
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: id#2 is "+sourceData[i][3]+", and name#2 = "+sourceData[i][4]); 

    // #3 ID and Name
    data.push({
      "id": sourceData[i][5],
      "name": sourceData[i][6]
    });
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: id#3 is "+sourceData[i][5]+", and name#3 = "+sourceData[i][6]); 

    // Logger.log(data);

    firestore.createDocument(title, data);

  }

}
```

---

**FYI**

[Google app script - looping through the rows in a spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41166944/1330560)

[Iterating over an object in a Google Apps script and printing to Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44145220/1330560) (Firebase specific)

Comment: don't forget to add the library: "libraryId": "1VUSl4b1r1eoNcRWotZM3e87ygkxvXltOgyDZhixqncz9lQ3MjfT1iKFw"        and you are missing an extra "}" . And it works.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a **[for in loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)** used to create multiple documents in FireStore:

```
// Note: this Google Apps Script uses an external library as per this page:
// https://github.com/grahamearley/FirestoreGoogleAppsScript

function testMultiWrites() {
  const email = 'sheets@yourprojectid.iam.gserviceaccount.com';
  const key = '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nPRIVATEKEY\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n';
  const projectID = 'yourprojectid';
  var firestore = FirestoreApp.getFirestore(email, key, projectID);
  var collection = "TestMutliWrites";

  const data = [
    {
      "id": "proveedor1",
      "name": "direccion1"
    },
    {
      "id": "proveedor2",
      "name": "direccion2"
    },
    {
      "id": "proveedor3",
      "name": "direccion3"
    }
  ];

  for (let i in data) {
    try {
      firestore.createDocument(collection + "/", data[i]);
    }
    catch (e) {
      //Console.log("Error: " + e); // << If you print to a browser console
      //Logger.log("Error: " + e); // << If you print to Google Apps Script Logger
    }
  }
}
```